# Push local folder to git using Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, github

Is there anyway I can push a local folder to git other from jenkins **on Windows** other then create a Windows bash job and execute the `git push origin master` command that get te job to get stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discoverd **Git Publisher** plug-in which does exactly what I need.